# How to create a large navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a menu that contains groups, and items.

Currently it the code looks something along these lines

```
<div id="Layer_01_Category_01_Header" class="Some classes here">
</div>
<div id="Layer_01_Category_01_Content" class="Some classes here">
    <div id="Layer_02_Category_01_Header" class="Some classes here">
    </div>
    <div id="Layer_02_Category_01_Content" class="Some classes here">
        <div id="Layer_03_Category_01_Header" class="Some classes here">
        </div>
        <div id="Layer_03_Category_01_Content" class="Some classes here">
            ITEMS HERE
        </div>
        <div id="Layer_03_Category_02_Header" class="Some classes here">
        </div>
        <div id="Layer_03_Category_02_Content" class="Some classes here">
            ITEMS HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks: https://gyazo.com/74e407b749e3a05574703e5c3b2256b3

This is how is supposed to work:

- 1) user clicks open a group (With the white triangle on the left side of the box)
- 2) The items (Light grey background) belonging to that group get loaded and the user can click on one of the items to see more information about it (Information displayed on another div, outside of the menu)
- 3) User opens another group. The previously open group gets closed and the contents get hidden/removed

I hope you get the idea... (I am bad at explaining things).

Now... I have tried doing this manually, adding a div for each item, but it does not feel like the right way to do this because:

- A) The HTML code is already around 400 lines
- B) The load times for the page will get longer and longer the more I keep expanding this menu (I assume?)

How could I go populating the groups with items in some automated way? What I had in mind is running a script when a group is opened that populates it with items from a database/xml file but I would like to hear other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume following things.

1. The depth of hierarchy can be any level.
2. Length of each level can be any thing.

I would recommend to change Menu from Accordion to Cascading style.

1. If depth of hierarchy is more, possibly you could end-up with half displayed name with ellipsis when depth shift more in column width. Please see following
   [image]
2. If number of item in single hierarchy is more, the you could end-up, vertical scrollbar. Again user experience will be inconsistent with viewing experience.
   [image]
   It would be better you can use `cascading menu style` in this case. Please see following picture.
   [image]
   However, for this kind of menu style either static or dynamic loading will work. Though, I would recommend static menu loading and use css to handle hover and show & hide.

Note: Since the combined approach(accordion+tree) is not nice fit for multi-level and multiple menu items, I just recommended right approach. And I believe, it requires only little study in css properties like, position, z-index, display or visible. I left those things for you.